# asp.net mvc using url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There are VideoAlbum controller and Video controller. When I want to create a video, albumId comes from url.(http://localhost:38500/Admin/Video/Create?albumId=0)

In Creat(video) I am taking video name and some information. I want to post albumId with these information.

Here is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Video", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset id="Proje_Bilgileri">
         <div >
            @Html.Label("Ad:")
        </div>
        <div >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div >
            @Html.Label("Kaynak:")
        </div>
        <div >
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Data)
        </div>


    </fieldset> 

    <input class="button" id="formuGönder" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: hmm, the question is not so clear. I think people won't like it this way. You should give more information (your controller code, mapRoute code, models, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing how you persist your videos to a database for example, it is hard to answer this question.

But if you are using a database, it should be your database that should be creating the new video id so you 
do not need to pass it.

Instead your create action should be something similar to below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Video video)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Videos.Add(video);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");  
  }
}
```

You can see this in the music store [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-5)